# Regex will match 2 specific patterns

Tags: regex

I need some help with Regular Expressions.

The RegEx should match the 2 patterns below:

Case 1:
XT123456 when matched then return value = 123456

Case 2:
1234567 when matched then return value = 1234567

other values (12345, XT1234567, T123456, etc) should be discarded.

Some help will be very appreciated, thanks

Regards,

Manu

Comment: So only match Numbers with a length above 5? Try  `[0-9]{5,}`

Comment: why instead of downvoting, do not downvote and bring a solution, it's easy to criticize the others, too easy, cheers

Comment: @Cataklysim above 5 but not only, if the value begins with XT should be followed by 6 digits (XT123456), otherwise that's not a valid value, if the values is 7 digits is valid, if I try your regex with XT123456 won't work, thanks

Comment: Yes I understand your point and I think in the same way as you do, but sometimes its just too much and you can't comment every question what is wrong. There is a perfect example for questions and this site will show you how to write a good one.

Comment: [`\b(?:XT\K\d{6}|\d{7})\b`](https://regex101.com/r/n8GI2b/1)

Answer (score 0):

You should work with the two patterns separately in the first place.

Here is my expression for the first pattern :

```
(?<=XT)(\d{6}(?!\d))
```

It means the digits you search must start with a the 'XT' but without capturing it and must not end with another digit, to limit the capturing expression to 6 digits.

The second expression for the other pattern :

```
(?<!XT)(\d{7}(?!\d))
```

Unlike the first one, I exclude the digits to start with the 'XT' text and must not end with another digit to keep the limit at 7 digits.

Then combine the two patterns together :

```
(?<=XT)(\d{6}(?!\d))|(?<!XT)(\d{7}(?!\d))
```

You can try it yourself here : https://regex101.com/r/cbn4XJ/1/